# Use Firebug to change location of an external javascript file to a lower position of an HTML file

Tags: javascript, html, firebug

I am trying to find if I can use Firebug to move a js file from its current location to a point further down in the html file. Below is a generic example of what I want to do.

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="external file.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>

<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<script src="external file.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

So is there a way using Firebug, to move the javascript file from the head to the body?

Thanks for all the help.

Comment: I'm sorry, but I don't understand what you're trying to accomplish. Firebug is just a debugging tool. Can you not just move it in the source HTML file?

Comment: You can do it running a script on your script panel.

Answer (score 0):

By the time Firebug comes in to picture, the script would have already been parsed and executed by browser's engine. Firebug was not meant for this purpose.

Another way to achieve what you want is to install [Fiddler2](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/) which lets you set a breakpoint in a request (in this case add a breakpoint to the request for the html) and then edit the response (the html sent from server). This happens before the page is received by the browser.